# Lua - Evaluate script as a value using C API

Tags: c, lua

I would like to use Lua not only for writing scripts in separate files, but I would also like to embed Lua expressions into configuration properties.

For example :

```
{
    "MyConfigProperty" : "Hello mister {{ app:getUserName() }} !"
}
```

Here `app:getUserName()` would return a string and the the whole script contained in `{{` `}}`, which is actually just an expression, could be evaluated to a string value.

How could I "call" this piece of Lua code so that it is evaluated and leaves a string value on the stack ?

One solution could be to wrap it into a `"return (" + expression + ")"` as suggested in the Lua documentation. 
Running this should (I guess) leave the resulting string on the stack as a return value. But this could be a problem because then I would not be able to determine when a string was successfully returned and when an error message was returned do to a failure in the execution.

How could I do that using the C API **without losing the capability of detecting errors** ? Thank you.

**EDIT** : Another solution could be to prefix with `return nil,` and then check the type of the first return value. If the first return value is nil, get the successfully evaluated value which is the second return value. Else if the first return value is a string, an error occured. There might have been a cleaner approach though.

Comment: The return value of [`lua_pcall`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_pcall) will tell you whether an error occurred or not. You don't have to inspect the Lua stack for that.

Comment: @siffiejoe Isn't pcall returning the number of values returned by the function that was pushed on the stack by a previous call to lua_loadfile ?

Comment: No. You can pass the number of return values you want as the third argument to `lua_pcall()`, and Lua will adjust the real number of values to the requested number of values. If you pass `LUA_MULTRET` this adjustment will not take place and you have to figure out the number of return values by comparing the result of `lua_gettop()` before and after the call.

Comment: [lua_pcall](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pcall)

Comment: Okay thanks for your help.